# Where is the information about custom launchers in Unity panel?

Tags: unity, launcher, customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)

I have recently pinned my "custom" application to the Unity launcher bar. I'd like to tweak it a bit, add a description and maybe and icon for easier alt-tab recognition. However, I was not able to find where is the launcher bar information stored.

I have followed some older guides and looked to ~/.local/share/applications but nothing correspoding to my launcher is there. How (where) can I find that file(s) describing my launchers?

Answer (score -2):

There is a unity documentation project, which does claim to have written some info. They don't seem to have done a good job of presenting this documentation to users though. Don't have time to search at the moment...